# Angular2 function call throws typeerror

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function in my service, corresponding to this code:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyService {
constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {}
        getInfo() {
            return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => {return JSON.parse(response)}
        }
    }
```

This method is getting called from `ngOnInit` of a component as mentioned below:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private service: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getInfo().subscribe((data) => {
                    this.info = data;
                });
    }
}
```

The issue is when I am navigating to this component, by putting the url on browser, it works fine, but when I navigate to this component, using `router.navigate` method, it throws an exception,

> getInfo is not a function

Please correct me where is the problem and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show what else there in the code

Comment: How did you inject your service?

Comment: Are you sure that you inject service to your component? Can you show constructor of component, where do you call service method?

Answer (score 2):

You should inject your service to component, where do you use it. You can do that, declararing service as a parameter of your component's constructor. For example:

**simple.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    someMethod() { //some method }
}
```

**some.component.ts**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.simpleService.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, if this a solution but ")" character is missing in your service's method. It should look like that:

```
return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => {return JSON.parse(response)})
```

or even:

```
return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

Comment: Service is already injected as you have mentioned, but still facing the issue

Comment: @AnkurMukherjee I edited my answer. Maybe, this is a solution. If not, tell me